# How to disable "schedule" if there is a condition on python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, schedule, telebot

I am writing a bot tc on the telebot library, I am trying to send a newsletter to the user, if he chooses "yes", then a message is sent to him every day, if he chooses "no", then the newsletter is either turned off or simply not turned on

```
import telebot
import schedule
import time
from telebot import types
if message.text == "Подборка книг":
    podborka = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да", callback_data="да")
    no = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет", callback_data="нет")
    podborka.add(yes,no)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Получать рассылку?", reply_markup=podborka)
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def callback_inline(call):
        def good_luck():
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Круто!")
        job = schedule.every(1).seconds.do(good_luck)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

        if call.message:
            if call.data == "да":
                godo()
            else:
                schedule.cancel_job(job)
```

Comment: need your imports to be able to understand what packages you are using.

Comment: import telebot
import schedule
import time
from telebot import types

Comment: The schedule library has a cancel method that you can pass a variable holding job reference to: schedule.cancel_job(job).   you can also get a list of jobs and probably cancel from that?

Answer (score 0):

In your example above you could tag the job you create like so:

```
job = schedule.every(1).seconds.do(good_luck).tag("my_job")
```

Then later on when you need to clear it out do  this:

```
schedule.clear('my_job')
```

Comment: i tried that, but it also don't work,  i need to bot sends an information every day if guy turn on this function, if he doesn't - turn off sending